# Chrome Extension Tabs onUpdated with status === 'complete' works too early

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

background.js

```
// create a new tab when alarmed
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
  if (alarm.name === 'myAlarm') {
    let tabId = 0;
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
      const url = 'https://www.vk.com/feed';
      chrome.tabs.create({ url }, (tab) => {
        tabId = tab.id!;
      });
    });
  }
});

// wait till the new tab will load completely to do the stuff with DOM in the new tab from content.js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
      if (tab.url!.indexOf('https://www.vk.com/feed') != -1 && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
      // setTimeout
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
          from: Sender.React,
          message: 'GET_COOKIES'
        });
      }
    });
```

I've tried this code above, but it doesn't work
I am getting status === 'complete' and sending messages to my content.js too early when DOM is not ready (content.js can't find an element and doesn't do anything when it's getting 'GET_COOKIES' message)
When I add setTimeout, with, for example, 3000ms for sending messages - that's works fine!
But I don't want to do this, because some users can have an unstable connection and they will need more than 3 seconds, and some will need less than 3 seconds with more good connection
I've tried 'onHistoryStateUpdated' with 'webNavigation' - but it seems doesn't work too

How should I resolve this?
Please, help...

Comment: Modern sites add elements *after* DOM is complete (DOM that was built from the initial server response). Use MutationObserver to wait for the element in your content script.

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a long-term solution to this? I'm having the exact same issue. A MutationObserver is overkill for my purposes, I have no interest in seeing what has been added to the DOM, I just need to know when it's fully finished loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var exUrl = ''    

if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && exUrl != tab.url) {
    exUrl = tab.url;
}
```

well, i used this trick. 
maybe changInfo.status sends complete signal part by part? 
i don't know what exactly happened but this worked for me

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand, what exactly is the "trick" happening here? I understand what's happening in the code but I don't understand how exactly this fixes the issue.

Comment: when chrome try to load new page, change.status has returned with three different times. 1st, changed.status == 'complete' with "current" page, 2nd, changed.status == '???(sorry i forgot)' several times while loading "new" page, and finally changed.status == 'complete' with "new" page. so, i put this shape of code to listener to make sure this listener works "after" url has changed and completly loaded.